# Manually Verifying PEM Certificates in Go?

Tags: ssl, go, x509

My situation is such: I am manually verifying the Splunk instance's server cert to my client application. I create a new httpclient wrapper with this method. Can someone explain to me exactly what I am to do? My guess is that to 1. there is no IP address designated as the CA, 2. Some config file screaming out, 3. No idea

```
const SplunkPEM = `---BEGIN...jsldfjklsd---END`

func NewHttpClient() (*http.Client, error) {
rootcas := x509.NewCertPool()
ok := rootcas.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(SplunkPEM))
if !ok {
    return http.DefaultClient, ErrString("Failed to parse PEM!")

}

conf := &tls.Config{
    MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
    RootCAs:    rootcas,
    ServerName: "SplunkServerDefaultCert",
}
tr := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: conf}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
return client, nil
}
```

error 1:
cannot validate certificate for 10.0.0.112 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
--so I tried changing

```
&tls.Config{
ServerName: "SplunkServerDefaultCert",
}
```

error 2:
 certificate is valid for SplunkServerDefaultCert, not splunk.com

error 3:
certificate is not authorized to sign other certificates

Comment: Why don't you use [Certificate.Verify()](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#Certificate.Verify)?

Comment: My client is trusting the PEM cert. SplunkPEM is my root cert, the public key portion. Trust this = trust server's cert is my understanding yikes idk yet.

Comment: This looks like not a XY problem but perhaps you're looking for `tls.Config`'s `Verify` field.

Comment: It is something specific to Splunk. This works for other services that use self-signed certificates.